# Pass value to modal on button click

Tags: javascript, html, button, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I wanted to show the further details of my card in modal when the user click the button "More Details" ,i have seen an answer regarding to this however I don't want the information to be inside an input field. Can please someone help me with it?

```
 <button class="open-homeEvents btn btn-primary" data-id="2014-123456"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalHomeEvents">More Details</button>
```

**MODAL**

```
<div id="modalHomeEvents" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="height:50px;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

         <label>Student ID</label>     
        <input type="hidden" name="eventId" id="eventId"/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" name="login" style="background-color:rgb(0,30,66); ">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).on("click", ".open-homeEvents", function () {
     var eventId = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body #eventId").val( eventId );
});</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using an input field you could create a container element for the id, a `div` or `span` and update content of the element using `.html()` jQuery method.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".open-homeEvents", function () {
     var eventId = $(this).data('id');
     $('#idHolder').html( eventId );
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Modal</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<body>
<button class="open-homeEvents btn btn-primary" data-id="2014-123456"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalHomeEvents">More Details</button> 
<div id="modalHomeEvents" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="height:50px;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

         <label>Student ID</label>     
        <input type="hidden" name="eventId" id="eventId"/>
         <span id="idHolder"></span> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" name="login" style="background-color:rgb(0,30,66); ">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: however, the <span></span> kept on repeating when you click the button

Comment: You are right, apologies. Updated my answer. If you have no issue with using `.html()` then this should work.